# Можно ли обрабатывать сторонние GET/POST запросы в Aiogram 3 телеграм боте на Webhook?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Предположим что есть платежка, которая при успешном платеже посылает запрос на мой URL. Если я хочу чтобы бот реагировал на запрос, мне обязательно писать его на Flask/FastAPI? Или есть какой-то способ на вебхуках в Aiogram 3. Спасибо!

Просто aiogram знаю гораздо лучше чем само Telegram API и веб-фреймворки.

Comment: средствами aiogram этого не получится сделать. aiogram 3 версии идет в комплекте с aiohttp, вот с помощью него уже можно это сделать